# Increase or decrease a number by "x" percentage

Tags: python, math

How do I increase or decrease an "X" number by a certain amount of percentage say, 2% or 3%?

Case scenario: My value is 5 - I want to increase this number by 2% - so the final value will be 5.1 after 2% percentage increase.

And the same would be if I want to decrease this number by an "X" percentage.

I hope that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: So what have you tried for code till Now

Comment: I don't think this is the place to explain absolute math basics. You might want to read about [Percentage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage) in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate a percentage in Python, use the division operator (/) to get the quotient from two numbers and then multiply this quotient by 100 using the multiplication operator (*) to get the percentage.

```
y=int(input("Enter Percentage: "))
x=5
x += (x * y/100)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
Enter Percentage: 2
5.1
```

For Decreasing Value:

```
y=int(input("Enter Percentage: "))
x=5
x -= (x * y/100)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
Enter Percentage: 2
4.9
```

Answer (score 1):

A percent is just a fraction of 100, so multiply by 1 + your percent over 100:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> x *= (1 + 2/100)
>>> x
5.1
```

Another way to think of it is incrementing `x` by `x` times that percent (these operations are algebraically equivalent):

```
>>> x = 5
>>> x += (x * 2/100)
>>> x
5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase by a percent, multiply the number by (1+{percent}). To decrease by a percent, multiply the number by `(1-{percent})`. Given your example:

- Increase 5 by 2%: `5*(1+0.02)=5*1.02=5.1`
- Decrease 5 by 2%: `5*(1-0.02)=5*0.98=4.9`.